# redis vs sqllite 3 (in memory)

Tags: sqlite, redis

I'm looking for a database that is

1. faster
2. supports concurrent  reads

so what should be my choice, redis or sqllite 3 (with in memory option) or something else.

Comment: What data would you store? Either way, this is an apples-and-oranges comparison: Redis talks over sockets (to multiple clients if need be), SQLite is a library in a single process.

Comment: i have a WebSocket stream, im trying to store that data in one module and other modules to read that saved data

Comment: If you need multiple processes to have access to the data while keeping it in memory, then out of these two options, Redis is the only valid one.

Comment: speed is my concern, not keeping it in memory. does redis supports concurrent read ?

Comment: Yes. But Redis is memory-only, so the size of your dataset is bounded by memory.

Answer (score 0):

would [Keydb](https://docs.keydb.dev/) maybe be what you are looking for? it's a drop in replacement for redis.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).